# join two group fields from the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a small table "Player 1" with two fields "week 1", "week 2" are fixed Winnings:

table player 1

```
Week 1    Week 2
 $ 50
 $ 50      $ 50
 $ 100     $ 100
 $ 100     $ 200
```

and I want to `COUNT` the two fields "week 1" and "week 2" and I want to look like this:

```
 fixed  COUNT week 1   COUNT week 2
$ 50         2              1
$ 100        2              1
$ 200        0              1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select fixed, sum(isweek1) as week1, sum(isweek2) as week2
from (select week1 as fixed, 1 as isweek1, 0 as isweek2
      from t
      union all
      select week2, 0 as isweek1, 1 as isweek2
      from t
     ) as x
group by fixed;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but it doesn't turn out that way. The field "fixed" does not exist, so I want to group those fixed for each week.

Comment: Gordon's code defines the field `fixed` within the subquery - you need only change `t` to the name of your table, e.g. `[player 1]`.

Comment: I want to join two queries:

SELECT week1, count (week1) AS con_week1
FROM player
GROUP BY week1

AND

SELECT week2, count (week2) AS con_week2
FROM player
GROUP BY week2

and the result of the two queries in the same rows.

Comment: @CarlosYague . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.